# counting based on a column and a string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have several documents and one df column that has particular words I need to search, how do I count the number of times the word showed up in the documents ?

An example is better.

**Example:**

```
doc1 = "I am a cat that barks. I like dog food instead of cat food. Roff"

doc2 = "Frog that barks. Frog like cats."

df['words'] = ["dog","cat","frog"]
```

[image]

Looking for it to turn into a df that would look like this.

It'd look something like this, but I realize it is just looping into the same cell. So I am always getting zero.

```
for i in range(len(doc)):
    for key, value in doc.items():
        for word in df['word']:
            df['doc_' + str(i)] = value.count(word)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
doc1 = "I am a cat that barks. I like dog food instead of cat food. Roff"
doc2 = "Frog that barks. Frog like cats."
strings = [doc1, doc2]
words = ["dog","cat","frog"]

def count_occ(word, sentence):
    return sentence.lower().split().count(word)    

cts = []

def counts_df(strings, words):    
    for w in words:
        for s in strings:
            cts.append(count_occ(w, s))
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(cts).reshape((len(words), len(strings))),
                      index=words, 
                      columns=['doc' + str(i) for i in range(1, len(strings) + 1)])    
    return df

counts_df(strings, words)
Out[61]: 
      doc1  doc2
dog      1     0
cat      2     0
frog     0     2
```